# how to create a dsn for oracleinxe?

Tags: java, odbc, oracle-xe

i have oracle 10g express edition installed and i want to know how to create a system dsn for it.so that i can connect database to my java programs

Answer (score 0):

We've found that [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-141217.html) ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)) is the best way to connect to an Oracle database from Java, but if you prefer to use ODBC, these instructions from the Oracle website should get you there.

> 1. Click Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Data Sources
>      (ODBC) to open the ODBC Data Source
>      Administrator.
> 2. Click the System DSN tab and click Add. The Create New Data Source dialog box
>      opens.
> 3. In the Create New Data Source dialog box, select the Oracle driver.
> 4. Click Finish to open the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration dialog box.
> 5. In the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration dialog box, enter a Data
>      Source Name (this can be any name),
>      select the appropriate TNS Service
>      Name from the drop down list, and enter  the
>      User ID for the schema.
> 6. Click Test Connection to open the Oracle ODBC Driver Connect dialog box.
> 7. In the Oracle ODBC Driver Connect dialog box, enter the password for
>      the schema and click OK.
> 8. You should see a "Testing Connection" message indicating the
>      connection is successful.
> 9. Click OK to close the Testing Connection message.
> 10. Click OK to close the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration dialog box.
> 11. Verify that the system data source is added in the ODBC Data
>       Source Administrator and click OK to
>       close the ODBC Data Source
>       Administrator.

If you go to [the original link](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/obe_bi/bi_ee_1013/bi_admin/biadmin.html#t1s2), they have screenshots too, but also a lot more information since they are part of the setup of a different product.